# I found this rock on Laguna Beach

Tags: rocks

Rock found on Laguna Beach. It is not sand stone and is heavy for its size 3" x 2". It is rather dense.

Click the image for full size:

[image]

Comment: Where is Laguna Beach? If you drop some vinegar on it, does it fizz?

Comment: Laguna Beach is in Orange County California. I did a little research on this rock, it's basalt. I'll try the vinegar.

Comment: If I would guess I would suggest that the rock is likely a granite, there are many varieties.  The color and what I suspect are crystal grains in the picture suggest that the rock is a Felsic rock, where some of the mineral crystals of unevenly weathered out.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felsic.

Comment: Crack it open and show us the fresh surface

Comment: This question already got a close vote because it does not contain enough information. Please [read this](http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/124/a-guide-for-asking-identify-this-rock-questions) and improve your question. Include your comment answers. And *heavy* says very little. Do you have a kitchen scale?

Comment: As it is, this post is not even a question. While we can get what OP want, it need to be properly formulated so that it can be at all useful in the future as part of the SE network.